# Camera code in polar coordinates

Tags: c++

I have OpenGL code for camera:

```
static float  angleX = 180;
static float angleY = 0;

POINT mousexy;
GetCursorPos(&mousexy);

int xt=400; 
int yt=300;

angleX +=(xt - mousexy.x)/7.0f;
angleY +=(yt - mousexy.y)/7.0f;

if (angleY<-89.0){angleY=-89.0;}
if (angleY>89.0){angleY=89.0;}

SetCursorPos(xt,yt);       

static vector3 vPos = vector3( 25.0, 5.0, 5.0);

float PI = 3.1415926f;
float speed = 25.0f;
float dx,dy,dz;
dx = dy = dz = 0.0f;

if(GetAsyncKeyState('W')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx =- sin(angleX/180*PI) * speed; 
         dz =- cos(angleX/180*PI) * speed;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('S')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin(angleX/180*PI) * speed;
         dz = cos(angleX/180*PI) * speed;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('D')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin((angleX+90)/180*PI) * speed;   
         dz = cos((angleX+90)/180*PI) * speed;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('A')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin((angleX-90)/180*PI) * speed;   
         dz = cos((angleX-90)/180*PI) * speed;
    }
    

    vPos.x += dx*fElaspedAppTime;
    vPos.y += dy*fElaspedAppTime; 
    vPos.z += dz*fElaspedAppTime; 


    vector3 vLook;
    vLook.x = vPos.x - sin(angleX/180*PI);
    vLook.y = vPos.y + tan(angleY/180*PI);
    vLook.z = vPos.z - cos(angleX/180*PI);
    

    gluLookAt(vPos.x, vPos.y, vPos.z,
        vLook.x, vLook.y, vLook.z,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    
    
    
    MeshManager.Draw_Mesh();
```

Code above works fine for OpenGL. I tried to transfer this code to my software rendering project (software triangle rasterization, perspective correct texture mapping) but camera is not woring properly. This is my code from softrend project (below):

```
matrix4x4 CMeshManager::Get_View_Matrix()
{
    float Time = Get_Elapsed_Time();

    UINT ScreenWidth = m_ViewWidth;
    UINT ScreenHeight = m_ViewHeight;

    POINT MousePos;
    GetCursorPos(&MousePos);
    
    SetCursorPos(ScreenWidth/2, ScreenHeight/2);
    
    static float DeltaX = 180;
    static float DeltaY = 0;

    DeltaX -=(( float(ScreenWidth/2)-MousePos.x) / 12.0f);
    DeltaY +=(( float(ScreenHeight/2)-MousePos.y) / 12.0f);

    float speed = 25.0f;
    float dx,dy,dz;
    dx = dy = dz = 0.0f;

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('W')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = -sin(DeltaX/180*PI) * speed; 
         dz = -cos(DeltaX/180*PI) * speed;

    
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('S')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin(DeltaX/180*PI) * speed;
         dz = cos(DeltaX/180*PI) * speed;

        
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('D')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin((DeltaX-90)/180*PI) * speed;   
         dz = cos((DeltaX-90)/180*PI) * speed;

    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('A')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin((DeltaX+90)/180*PI) * speed;   
         dz = cos((DeltaX+90)/180*PI) * speed;
    }
    

    m_VecPos.x += dx * Time;
    m_VecPos.y += dy * Time; 
    m_VecPos.z += dz * Time; 

    m_VecLook.x = -sinf(DeltaX/180*PI);
    m_VecLook.y = tanf(DeltaY/180*PI);
    m_VecLook.z = -cosf(DeltaX/180*PI);


    m_VecLook = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecLook);
    m_VecUp = Vec3_Cross(m_VecLook,m_VecRight);
    m_VecUp = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecUp);
    m_VecRight = Vec3_Cross(m_VecUp,m_VecLook);
    m_VecRight = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecRight);
    
    float xp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecRight);
    float yp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecUp);
    float zp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecLook);

    matrix4x4 MatView = matrix4x4(
        m_VecRight.x, m_VecUp.x, m_VecLook.x, 0,
        m_VecRight.y, m_VecUp.y, m_VecLook.y, 0,
        m_VecRight.z, m_VecUp.z, m_VecLook.z, 0,
        xp,       yp,    zp,      1 );

    return MatView;
}
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: How does the behaviour you observe differ from what you want/expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix4x4 CMeshManager::Get_View_Matrix()
{
    float Time = Get_Elapsed_Time();

    UINT ScreenWidth = m_ViewWidth;
    UINT ScreenHeight = m_ViewHeight;

    POINT MousePos;
    GetCursorPos(&MousePos);

    SetCursorPos(ScreenWidth/2, ScreenHeight/2);
    
    static float DeltaX = PI;
    static float DeltaY = 0;

    DeltaX -= (float(ScreenWidth/2)-MousePos.x) / 800;
    DeltaY -= (float(ScreenHeight/2)-MousePos.y) / 800;

    if (DeltaY<-PI/2.0f){DeltaY=-PI/2.0f;}
    if (DeltaY>PI/2.0f){DeltaY=PI/2.0f;}

    static vector3 m_VecPos = vector3( 25.0, 5.0, 5.0);

    float speed = 25.0f;
    float dx,dy,dz;
    dx = dy = dz = 0.0f;

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('W')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = -sin(DeltaX) * speed * Time; 
        dz = -cos(DeltaX) * speed * Time;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('S')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin(DeltaX) * speed * Time;
        dz = cos(DeltaX) * speed * Time;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('D')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin(DeltaX-PI/2.0f) * speed * Time;    
        dz = cos(DeltaX-PI/2.0f) * speed * Time;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState('A')& 0xFF00) 
    {
        dx = sin(DeltaX+PI/2.0f) * speed * Time;    
        dz = cos(DeltaX+PI/2.0f) * speed * Time;
    }

    m_VecPos.x += dx;
    m_VecPos.y += dy; 
    m_VecPos.z += dz; 

    vector3 m_VecUp = vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    vector3 m_VecRight, m_VecLook;

    m_VecLook.x = -sin(DeltaX);
    m_VecLook.y = -tan(DeltaY);
    m_VecLook.z = -cos(DeltaX);

    m_VecLook = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecLook);
    m_VecRight = Vec3_Cross(m_VecUp,m_VecLook);
    m_VecRight = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecRight);
    m_VecUp = Vec3_Cross(m_VecLook,m_VecRight);
    m_VecUp = Vec3_Normalize(m_VecUp);

    float xp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecRight);
    float yp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecUp);
    float zp = -Vec3_Dot(m_VecPos, m_VecLook);

    matrix4x4 MatView = matrix4x4(
        m_VecRight.x, m_VecUp.x, m_VecLook.x, 0,
        m_VecRight.y, m_VecUp.y, m_VecLook.y, 0,
        m_VecRight.z, m_VecUp.z, m_VecLook.z, 0,
        xp,       yp,    zp,      1 );

    return MatView;
}
```

Sorry for fuss, I fixed code, just should made local vars (not global):

```
    vector3 m_VecUp = vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    vector3 m_VecRight, m_VecLook;
```

This vars was global vars, and it cause problems.

And first should made cross product with VecUp and VecLook, then VecRight.